# Code block in a browser for bash commands ignoring path

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to develop a user friendly way for styling the code highlighting for bash commands. Ill clarify the question using the example from [this page](https://themeaningfulengineer.github.io/Linux-kernel-in-QtCreator/).

On the animation below, you can see that someone following the tutorial who want's to copy the commands will also copy the path example, making the copy-paste process more complicated.

[image]

The path needs to be there because it shows the person what the current working directory is.

I would like to have only the commands selectable as shown on the picture below:

[image]

I don't know much about HTML, CSS and Javascript and am looking for a suggestion on how to approach this.

Can it be done purely by CSS by having custom classes for the specific part of the text?

Or can a Javascript script automatically detect a `$` on a line and automatically disable selecting for certain parts? Would this be resource intensive?

Comment: The process should be achievable using either `html` and `css` or `javascript`. Is expected result only applying style to rendered `html`; or are you also trying to get the commands text?

Comment: Mahybe you can do it by having the prompt in one DIV, the code in another DIV, and use `float: right` on the code DIV to merge them.

Comment: @guest271314 He's trying to arrange that when the user marks the commands with the mouse, it won't also copy the prompts.

Comment: @Barmar I think it will be much better to use the [`copy` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/copy)

Comment: Do you care about jQuery solutions? Or does it have to be vanilla javascript?

Comment: I removed my answer, as css solution did not work properly... I guess that the only solution left would be javascript to select elements you want onmouseup.

Comment: @Dekel I'm trying to not introduce additional dependencies to the site so a vanilla option would be better.

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer Note, at example images `pwd` is listed as `~/workspace/linux$` before `cd linux` which should not be possible, where `pwd` is `~/workspace` when `cd linux ` is run, yes?

Comment: @guest271314 Missed that, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `css` `:before` pseudo element

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

.command {
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: #eee;
  white-space: pre;
}

.command:nth-of-type(1n+1):before {
  content: "~/workspace$ ";
  background: #ccc;
}

.command:nth-of-type(2) ~ .command:before {
  content: "~/workspace/linux$ ";
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<code class="command"> git clone http://github.com/torvalds/linux.git</code><br>
<code class="command"> cd linux</code><br>
<code class="command"> make clean</code><br>
<code class="command"> make tinyconfig</code><br>
<code class="command"> make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 | tee build.log</code><br>
```

Comment: You got my vote! great solution :) you can check the change i made in my answer (which is based on yours).

Answer (score 3):

This solution is based on @guest271314 solution, so all the credit should go to him!

Here is an "upgrade version" which doesn't require you to put the values in the CSS:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

.command {
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
  text-overflow: wrap;
  background: #eee;
  white-space: pre;
}
.command:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<code class="command" data-content="~/workspace $ "> git clone http://github.com/torvalds/linux.git</code><br />
<code class="command" data-content="~/workspace $ "> cd linux</code><br />
<code class="command" data-content="~/workspace/linux $ "> make clean </code><br />
<code class="command" data-content="~/workspace/linux $ "> make tinyconfig </code><br />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `::before` pseudo-element to contain the directories, as they're not selectable by default. In example:

```
<style>
  p::before { 
    content: attr(data-dir);
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
</style>

<p data-dir="user@system:/stuff">git init</p>
<p data-dir="user@system:/stuff">git add -A .</p>
<p data-dir="user@system:/stuff">git commit -m "Lorem ipsum dolor"</p>
```

I've made a Plunker to test this, you can see it here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/43TM1FXBXQlZvEcsmLDL?p=preview